# How to dynamically add a page number in footer in Microsoft OXML c#

Tags: c#, footer, openxml, page-numbering

I'm creating a word document using OXML in Visual Studio. I don't know how long it is going to be and I need to add a simple page number in the footer of the document.

To generate headers and footers I used this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355228(v=office.12).aspx

As I understand, this presets the default headers/footers before I even write anything in the document. So I'm not quite sure if I can add page numbering to this? I'd really appreciate the help, because I've been stuck on this for a whole day...

Answer (score 10):

You can add dynamic page numbers by adding a [`SimpleField`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.simplefield(v=office.15).aspx) with an `Instruction` of `"PAGE"`. Word will automatically update any such field with the correct page number.

In order to code that you can adapt the `GeneratePageFooterPart` in the link you provided to include a `SimpleField` in the `Run` that gets added to the `Footer`:

```
private static Footer GeneratePageFooterPart(string FooterText)
{
    var element =
        new Footer(
            new Paragraph(
                new ParagraphProperties(
                    new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Footer" }),
                new Run(
                    new Text(FooterText),
                    // *** Adaptation: This will output the page number dynamically ***
                    new SimpleField() { Instruction = "PAGE" })
            ));

    return element;
}
```

Note that you can change the format of the page number by postfixing the `PAGE` text. From the [Ecma Office Open XML Part 1 - Fundamentals And Markup Language Reference.pdf](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm):

> When the current page number is 19 and the following fields are updated:
>
> PAGE
>   PAGE \* ArabicDash
>   PAGE \* ALPHABETIC
>   PAGE \* roman
>
> the results are:
>
> 19
>   - 19 -
>   S
>   xix

So to get roman numerals for example you would need to change the `SimpleField` line of code above to:

```
new SimpleField() { Instruction = "PAGE \\* roman" })
```

or (if you prefer)

```
new SimpleField() { Instruction = @"PAGE \* roman" })
```

Comment: What would the instruction be for something like "Page X of Y"?  =)

Comment: Glad my answer helped you @William - have you got it working as you want?

Comment: Sure did.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   private static void GenerateFooterPartContent(WordprocessingDocument package, string text = null)
    {
        FooterPart footerPart1 = package.MainDocumentPart.FooterParts.FirstOrDefault();
        if (footerPart1 == null)
        {
            footerPart1 = package.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<FooterPart>();
        }

        var relationshipId = package.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(footerPart1);
        // Get SectionProperties and set HeaderReference and FooterRefernce with new Id
        SectionProperties sectionProperties1 = new SectionProperties();
        FooterReference footerReference2 = new FooterReference() { Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default, Id = relationshipId };
        sectionProperties1.Append(footerReference2);
        package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(sectionProperties1);


        Footer footer1 = new Footer();


        Paragraph paragraph2 = CreateParagraph(package, string.Empty, "Footer");
        Run r = new Run(new SimpleField() { Instruction = "DATE" });          

        paragraph2.Append(r);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        {
            r = new Run();
            PositionalTab positionalTab1 = new PositionalTab() { Alignment = AbsolutePositionTabAlignmentValues.Center, 
                RelativeTo = AbsolutePositionTabPositioningBaseValues.Margin, 
                Leader = AbsolutePositionTabLeaderCharValues.None };

            r.Append(positionalTab1);
            paragraph2.Append(r);
            r = new Run(new Text(text) { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve });
            paragraph2.Append(r);
        }

        r = new Run();
        PositionalTab positionalTab2 = new PositionalTab() { Alignment = AbsolutePositionTabAlignmentValues.Right, 
            RelativeTo = AbsolutePositionTabPositioningBaseValues.Margin, 
            Leader = AbsolutePositionTabLeaderCharValues.None };

        r.Append(positionalTab2);
        paragraph2.Append(r);

        r = new Run(new Text("Page: ") { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve },
              // *** Adaptation: This will output the page number dynamically ***
              new SimpleField() { Instruction = "PAGE" },
              new Text(" of ") { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve },
              // *** Adaptation: This will output the number of pages dynamically ***
              new SimpleField() { Instruction = "NUMPAGES" });
        paragraph2.Append(r);

        footer1.Append(paragraph2);

        footerPart1.Footer = footer1;
    }
```

Refer to the following [link](http://officeopenxml.com/WPfieldInstructions.php)  for more instructions.